# for文とif文を使ったリスト内の要素の書き換えについて

Tags: python, numpy

初心者のため，質問の仕方が判りにくかったら申し訳ありません．

Python3で行列を作成し，inputの結果によって行列内の要素を置換するコードを書こうとしています．

図中のbasic_matrixで任意の要素数の行列を作成するまでは出来たのですが，行列内の要素全てについてinputで「"関係性がある（1）か，ない（0）か"」を入力させ，その値をbasic_matrixに反映させるためには，どのようにコードを書けば良いでしょうか．
とりあえず今は画像のように，入力値に応じて文書を返すようにしたのですが，それもうまくいっていません．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: これ [forループでリストの中身を書き換える方法　Python勉強記録](http://python.slightlysimple.net/entry/2014/04/28/181633) を参考に。

Comment: ありがとうございます．参考にします．

Answer (score 3):

inputは文字列（str）を受け取っているので、整数（int）と比較するとすべてNGになります。

```
if int(input("関係性がある場合…以下略"))==1:
```

という風に整数に変換すれば入力値にちゃんと反応するようになります。

もし配列（basic_matrix）の中身と比較したいのであれば、

```
print(basic_matrix ==1)
```

上記をfor文の外に書いてやれば配列の形のまま、合致するものをTrue、そうでないものをFalseで返します。↓

```
[[ True False False False False]
 [False  True False False False]
 [False False  True False False]
 [False False False  True False]
 [False False False False  True]]
```

参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 解決しました．ありがとうございます！